# how can we read a file using rest Api, which is locally present in my system?

Tags: java

I have to make a controller class and there I have to define get method to read a txt file which i have in my local storage.[I made a controller and I don't know if it is really a correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYnCL.png)

Comment: what error you are getting & also is it not possible to put file into some sort of `resources` folder of your project?

Comment: With attached image, which i suggest to put it as code just return br.readLine() if its the things you want to achive .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your text file has new lines. So can you try using streams?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/file")
    String getData(){
       String strLine="";
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/path"))))
        {
            strLine= br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));  //this way next line text can also be returned into existing string & strLine will looks like exactly as your text file content
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      return strLine;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I am able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do so, one practice as follow

```html
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/file")
    ResponseEntity<?> inquiryAdAccess(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/path"))))
        {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body( br.readAllLines());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Robinkumar Then please approve it as answer to improve the community.

Comment: When i run the code only one line of the txt file I am getting as output. @Lunatic

Comment: @Robinkumar use the method readAllLines() for getting all lines :)

Comment: readAllLines() is not working i am getting error